# Does being a Christian necessitate a belief in the supernatural?

Tags: culture, atheism

Consider a person who adheres to the scientific philosophy that the laws of nature are the same in all places and all times, and can be determined through experimentation rather than, for example, by divine revelation.

Can this person who adheres to such a philosophy ever become a Christian? As in a follower of the teachings of Jesus of Nazereth? e.g. be good to your neighbours, turn the other cheek, don't murder, etc.

If not what can you call a person who follows Christian philosophy and morals (as oppose to say Islamic philosophy) but does not believe in the possibility of the supernatural. The teachings may be so ingrained in them that they see these morals as self evident. Even though they don't base their behaviour on a desire to live on in an afterlife.

(As an example, in the Jewish tradition there is no heaven as such, and yet Jews have a strict moral code.)

Comment: Wouldn't God at least be above nature (super natural)?

Comment: @Sola Yes. Can you not follow  the teachings of Jesus without believing in God?

Comment: Jesus, who links His authority solely in God who sent Him? Or a different one?

Comment: @Sola Well it was 2000 years ago, so we can't say for sure whether he actually claimed to be the son of God. Or whether that was attributed to him at a later date. In fact the bible says he was quite vague about the subject when asked.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it demonstrates a lack of research. God himself is above nature and thus supernatural.

Comment: For the scholarly purposes of this site, a Christian is anyone who self-identifies as a Christian. People who call themselves Christians have many different definitions for what it means to be Christian, so you will need to specify who's (as in, which denomination's) definition you would like to learn about.

Comment: _He that cometh to God must believe that he is._ Hebrews 11:6. _God is a spirit_ said Jesus. Of course one must believe in the supernatural. Of course.

Comment: @NigelJ there are atheists who consider themselves Christian (they do call themselves Christian Atheists, check them in Wikipedia). I doubt they believe in the supernatural, but for the purposes of this site we have to consider then Christian.

Comment: @MattGutting My comment is carefully worded. One is included : not one is excluded.

Comment: I'm still not getting it, but that kind of discussion belongs in chat and I can't chat now.

Comment: "Well it was 2000 years ago, so we can't say for sure whether he actually claimed to be the son of God. Or whether that was attributed to him at a later date. In fact the bible says he was quite vague about the subject when asked." You don't get to discredit the source and then cite it as supporting your thesis lol.

Comment: There are a small number of people who claim to follow Christian principles without actually believing in anything supernatural, including the existence of God. (There are more who engage in Christian practice for cultural reasons without believing in Christian doctrine, including the existence of God). Discussion of whether these people can really call themselves 'Christian' is forbidden on this site, which is why your question is closed.

Comment: +1. It is a good question, and I think that the answer to that question is "yes", but that it only needs to be as big as a small seed at first; and that it will grow from there.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! It is written, “*Then I saw another angel flying in midair, and he had the eternal gospel to proclaim to those who live on the earth—to every nation, tribe, language and people.*” (Revelation 14:6, NIV)

That people includes many scientists who believe as you describe. Now Jesus described what becoming a Christian means:

> After John was arrested, Jesus went to Galilee, preaching the good
>   news of God:  “The time is fulfilled, and the kingdom of God has come
>   near. Repent and believe in the good news!” (Mark 1:14-15, HCSB)

Repenting means to change your mind, to agree with God about certain things that you did not believe before, both to agree that your behavior and morals are imperfect and need to change, as well as form new ideas about God.

Jesus promised his disciples that after he rose from the dead, he would send the Holy Spirit. This happened in the Book of Acts. A prominent emphasis in Acts is the baptism by the Holy Spirit. Just as Jesus told Nicodemus, to become a Christian, you must be born from above, aka born again. That is what the church taught and teaches still.

Jesus said that every blasphemy will be forgiven - even blasphemy against his name - but not blasphemy against the Holy Spirit. (See Matthew 12:31-32.)

Therefore, the proof of necessary repentance is God’s gift of the Holy Spirit. The Holy Spirit is supernatural. Thus the scientist who does not believe in the supernatural can become a Christian, but in the process, they will as a consequence of God’s activity in their life repent of their unbelief and acknowledge what God has done.

In other words, dry things can become wet if you pour water on them. Unspiritual people can become Spiritual if the Spirit is poured on them.

> “For you are saved by grace through faith, and this is not from
>   yourselves; it is God's gift — not from works, so that no one can
>   boast. (Ephesians 2:8-9, HCSB)

Comment: Interesting. So you're saying that to become a Christian, you in effect have to come to a belief in the supernatural.

Comment: There is a difference between disbelief in the supra natural and being  metaphysically skeptical. There are psychological and phenomenological approaches to religion that minimize metaphysical commitments. See James, varieties of religious experience for psychology. See process theology for a metaphysical skeptical take on religion. Are these approaches consistent with orthodox Christianity? Probably not. But why worry about how some person/group is going to label you?

Comment: @zooby - No, what I am saying is that having become a Christian, you will come to a belief in the supernatural (if you did not already have such a belief). The cause and effect are the reverse of what you say. Once you invite God in, he truly enters into you and performs a radical transformation of your thought processes, desires, goals, etc. This is called conversion, and it is more than superficial (if it is genuine).